# Building an Android project from the command line with Docker

Tags: java, android, docker, command-line-interface, development-environment

I inherited Android Java-code in my company, without Gradle-files etc, and I want to be able to compile this on my dev-server (I program from a ChromeOS machine, hence a CLI SSH connection to a server where I do dev stuff). Now I found some Docker images like [this one](https://hub.docker.com/r/ksoichiro/android/) (which doesn't even have a working command line example) but I haven't managed to create an APK yet. What am I missing and how would you do this?

Comment: What error message do you have?

Answer (score 1):

You have three steps to do:

1. Migrate your project to gradle.

   It isn't too difficult since there are plenty of gradle project out there and you can try to follow them or just read ["Migrating to Gradle"](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/intellij_to_gradle) article.
2. Build project with gradle on local machine.

   If you migrated properly you can build your project in terminal like:

   `./gradlew assembleDebug`

   but it might be also assembleDevDebug or assembleProdRelease which depends on your `buildType` and `flavor` in gradle. Check which assembles are available by running:

   `./gradlew tasks`
3. Build project using Docker.

   Based on image you linked:

   `docker run -t -i ksoichiro/android -v /path/to/project:/workspace -w workspace /bin/sh -c "./gradlew assembleDebug"`

Comment: Could you add a little more information to the first point? Thanks already!

Comment: @LaPingvino I don't think so I can say more than: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-intellij-projects or: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects